# Testing the pointers in a linked list

Tags: c++, search, linked-list

I have a weird result when I run this code

```
void MovieDatabase:: showMovie(const string mtitle){
    cout << "The informations about the" << mtitle << endl;
    for(Movie* cur = headMovie; cur ->next !=NULL; cur= cur->next){
        if(cur -> title == mtitle){
            cout <<"Movie title is "<<  cur ->title << endl;    
            //cout < "The name of director is " << cur -> firstNameOfDirector << endl;
            cout << "The last name of director is " << cur -> lastNameOfDirector <<endl;
            cout << "The year that the movie is released " << cur -> year << endl;
            cout << "The day that the movie is released " << cur -> day << endl;
            cout << "The month that the movie is released " << cur -> month << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Here is the code that I'm checking for the movietitle and if they are in the linked list i'm printing detailed information about the film. However, as an output it just prints the line that is

```
cout << "The informations about the" << mtitle << endl;`
```

I could not understand what is the reason can anyone help?

Comment: Note that if there's only one movie, the condition `cur->next != NULL` would fail before entering the loop. You may have meant `cur != NULL`. But maybe your `headMovie` is a dummy node, I don't know.

Comment: Mmm actually I wrote something after for loop and it printed it for the size of movies. However, it does not enter in "if" part. But i'm just checking the title is the same with the one that come as a parameter.

Comment: have you tried to debug your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure your strings really are equal, and there's not a hidden `\r` or `\n` or trailing spaces in one of them.

Also as mentioned in the comments, you probably want your loop termination condition to be `cur != NULL` and not `cur->next != NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1. You have no movies in your list whose title is `mtitle`.
2. You have a movie with that title, but it is the last movie in your list. Your `while` loop ends as soon as you get to the last movie (the one whose `next == NULL`) without checking it.

Without knowing the contents of your list we cannot know which is the case here.